# java processing order of annotation and static blocks

Tags: java, static, annotations

What is processed earlier - `static` block or `annotation`?

For example what is the order of processing the class like this

```
@CustomAnnotation
class TemplateClass {
    static {}
}
```

where class has some `annotation` and `static` block.

Comment: - snip - see answer :)

Comment: In what situation would it matter? When you're querying a class's annotations it has already been loaded, and thus its static initialization block has been run. My tests show that the class's annotations are not yet loaded when trying to access them from the class's static initialization block. My version of java is Oracle Java 1.8.0_20 x64.

Comment: @Thomas That should be an answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun aye aye :)

Comment: Try getting/printing a annotation from a static initializer, and you get the annotation. Not sure thought it has to be like this for every `ClassLoader`...

Comment: @fabian you're right, but in that case the static block would still be processed/executed first (or at least its execution would start first).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are processed in different ways so there is no specific order. Annotations are just kept in the class metadata (reflection) and need to be accessed via reflection code while static blocks are executed when the class itself is loaded by the classloader. That said reflection can only access the annotation after the class has been loaded and thus you could say the static block is executed first (unless you're doing some evil reflection stuff in it, in which case I'm not sure what would happen - you might even break the application - and every time you do such a thing a kitten dies ;) ).

As an example consider this which is how you could "process" the annotation:

```
TemplateClass.class.isAnnotationPresent( CustomAnnotation.class );
```

Here `TemplateClass` will first be loaded if it hasn't already and during that the static block will be executed. Then, after you get access to the loaded class object, the annotation is "processed" by checking whether it exists on that class and taking appropriate action.

**Edit**: as commented by @fabian you could execute the line above inside the static block and it should work. That said the more correct answer probably is: the static block will still be executed first but execution won't finish until the annotation has been "processed".

There *is* one way to "process" annotations before the static block, however: they can be processed at compile time by an annotation processor or even the compiler, if it knows about those annotations. `@Deprecated` would be an example of this.

That said when and how annotations are processed does *not* depend on the annotation itself but on the code that uses it.